# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php

Here is my complete code....

Connect.php

```
$connect = @mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password, $db_name) or die ('error');
$select = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect) or die('check');
```

password .php

```
//forgot password update

include('C:\wamp\www\header.html');

//check if form has been submitted
include('C:\wamp\www\connect.php');


    //connecting to db
    $errors = array();


if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {



    if (empty($_POST['username']))

    {
        $errors[]='Please enter a username.';
    }

    else
    {
      $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['username']));
    }

    //check for current password
    if (empty($_POST['password']))

    {
        $errors[]='Current password does not match.';
    }

    else
    {
      $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['password']));
    }

    //check for a new password and match with confirm pass.

    if(!empty($_POST['password1']))
    {
        if($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['cpass'])
        {
            $errors[] = 'The entered password and confirm password do not match.';
        }
        else
        {
            $np = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['password1']));
        }
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
    //if everything is fine.

    //verify the entered email address and password.

    $q="SELECT username FROM users WHERE (username='$u' AND password=SHA1('$p'))";
    $r=@mysqli_query($connect,$q);
    $num = @mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if($num==1)
    //if it matches.

    //get user id
    {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM);

    //udpdate query.

    $q="UPDATE users SET password= SHA1('$np') WHERE username=$row[0]";

    $r=@mysqli_query($connect, $q);

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) ==1)

    {
        echo '<h3>Your password has been updated.</h3>';
    }

    else {
        echo '<h3>Whops! Your password cannot be changed due a system error. Try again later. Sorry</h3>';

    echo '<p>' .mysqli_error($connect). 'Query:' . $q.'</p>';
    }


    exit();
    }
    else 
    {

        //invalid email and password

        echo 'The entered username and password do not match.';
    }

}
    else 
    {
        //report the errors.

    echo '<h1> Err... </h1>
    <p> The following error(s) have occured</p>';

    foreach ($errors as $msg)
        {
            echo "--$msg<br />\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please Try Again.</p><p><br/></p>';

    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

    ?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Change your password</h1>
<form action="password.php" method="post">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username" size="20" maxlength="80" />
<br>
Current Password<br/>
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br/>
New Password<br/>
<input type="password" name="password1" />
<br/>
Confirm New Password<br/>
<input type="password" name="cpass" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password"/>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>
</form>
</div>

<?php
include('C:\wamp\www\footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: see if you have resource after connect to mysql

Comment: I am using pHpMyadmin to connect to db.

Comment: `$db_name` is a string, but needs to be a mysqli resource.

Comment: hey pekka...nice to hear from you....how do i make $db_name a resource.sorry for askig a dumb question.

Comment: can you please modify the code...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

**mysqli_real_escape_string**

> **Parameters**
>
> *link*
>
> Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()`
>
> *escapestr*
>
> The string to be escaped.
>
> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

The first parameter must be a link identifier and not a string containing the DB name as it seems to be.

Comment: I saw your comment from Pekka's one. In your `connect.php`, you should have a `$link = mysqli_connect(...)` (or something like that) Use `$link` instead of `$db_name`

Comment: i have edited my post which shows what my connect.php is...thanks again

Comment: actually now i am getting mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\password.php on line 27

Comment: You changed the 3 `mysqli_real_escape_string` with `mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, somestring);` ? Then do you have a silly `mysqli_close($connect)` somewhere ?

Comment: Oh right, `$connect = @mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password, $db_name) or die ('error');` instead of `$connect = @mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password) or die ('error');` like in the last example of the MANUAL http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Yep, I have changed all three with mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['password1'])); etc...and have removed the mysqli_close...still i have the same issue..thanks

Comment: okay..i edited my $connect to $connect = @mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password, $db_name) or die ('error');...now what?thank you so much.

Comment: It shouldn't have anymore errors now... `$connect` is a link identifier and can be the 1st parameter of `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: oh...unfortunately...i am getting the error...i have posted the complete edited password.php and connect.php code..please do have a look.u r great.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\password.php on line 27

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\password.php on line 39

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\password.php on line 52
The entered username and password do not match.
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\password.php on line 114

Comment: Duh! How can't I see that !! You're using Mysql_connect and try to use a mysqli function !!! Use `mysqli_connect`. And please, read the manual!

Comment: Yeah because : (a) `$select = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect) or die('check');` is useless now that you put your db name into the mysqli_connect (b) `$select = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect) or die('check');` is a mysql function and `$connect` used inside it is now a mysqli...

Comment: OH GEEZ, THANKS YOU SO VERY MUCH...THE ERRORS ARE GONE...U R A GENIUS...GREAT..VOTE UP FOR BEST ANSWER..THANKS.

Comment: THERE IS THIS ONE LAST ERROR I AM FACING..EVEN IF THE ENTERED USERNAME AND PASSWORD MATHC...IT SAYS "The entered username and password do not match."

Comment: No problem, seems like you're starting learning :) BTW, you should'nt use absolute path in includes of your app `include('C:\wamp\www\header.html');` 'cause the path might change when you'll upload it (well, if you want to use it not only in local ;))

Comment: Well, that's another problem. It's not a PHP error. It means that the username and password you entered are not in your database. You should ask another question on SO...

Comment: oh yeah..im a beginner....so what path should i use...i am trying to develop a web application.

Comment: nope..the username and password are in my database...if i log in using that username and password, i am being redirect to my dashboard.

Comment: Since all your files are in the root of your site, it may be `include('header.html');`. For your other problem, you should start another question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

first parameter must be a link identifier, a value returned by http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.init.php

Blockquote