# why am i getting an error from file mysqli/mysqli_driver.php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just uploaded my project to my website server and i am getting this error message when i click on my submit button for my logging in form.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 315
```

I have absolutely no errors on my local server and i am completely stumped on what the problem is. if some one could please help i would be greatly appreciative and much respect will be given.

My project is using codeigniters framework.

Comment: your error message is telling you that your `mysqli` connection is `boolean`, which most likely means `false`, which means the connection failed. You need to check your connection.

Comment: i was able to make the error go away by changing my database.php file switching my driver from mysqli to mysql. not sure why this works, you would think mysqli would work just fine. now when i press the login button it gets stuck on my login_validation function and the page just shows up blank. now i have no idea what to look at or fix. it works perfectly fine on my local server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli\_real\_escape\_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996024/mysqli-real-escape-string-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqli_real_escape_string() is used to prepare text data too be save in an SQL Record Column.<br>And the data being wrint to that column does not exist.<br><br>
```

Go to `mysqli_driver.php` to Line #315 and put an at mark in fron of the command to supress the warning.

From:

```
 mysqli_real_escape_string()
```

To:

```
 @mysqli_real_escape_string()
```

**If the value you are escaping is an integer, then use intval() instead:**

This will turn a NULL into a Zero

```
$var = intval($var);
```

Comment: i just searched my entire project folder and i see no file named mysqli_driver.php.

Comment: I ended up finding it, thank you soooo much!!!! i do not know why when i used sublimes search that file did not come up. anyways you are a life saver, thank you.

Comment: No - __don't__ use `@` to suppress the error. Your code will fail unexpectedly, or you leave it open to SQL Injection attacks. You need to find the cause of this error (probably a database connection failure) and fix it.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it. it works perfectly fine on my local server. what else would you suggest?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a Warning.  It may be normal for for that field to be NULL. If the suppression of the Warning is an issue it will surface as either an SQL error, or bad data being stored.  Suppression is the correct first step.

Comment: everything is crapping out errors since i uploaded it to my server, i am now getting this error message:Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/recipes.php

Line Number: 35

Comment: why am i getting all these erros after loading to y server when everything works perfect with no error on my local server?? i am not going to have any hair by the end of tonight.

Comment: I wish i knew to start one. do you have skype?

Comment: @Misunderstood _' Suppression is the correct first step.'_ - you're not serious? Leave any errors unfixed and just cover up the damage? In this case the first parameter to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is a `mysqli` connection object. If that's a boolean the database connection has failed which is almost certainly a terminal error.

Comment: it seems as if anytime my site needs to use my database it throws out an error such as my foreach error. Must be a connection error, the problem is what is causing it. again it works perfect on my local server.

Comment: Misunderstood where you saying that their is a way to chat on the stack-overflow site?i did not know that had a chat option.Again, thank you for your help

Comment: @Misunderstood Please - just take a look at the PHP reference for [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). If you know what you're doing I'm a monkey's uncle.

Comment: @HoboSapiens The @ only suppresses the Warning, it does not disable the command. The worst that could happen is a NULL value would be entered in to that column if the command did fail.  BTW I talked with the OP on the phone and got him up and running.

Comment: Thanks @Misunderstood for helping me figure out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hide warnings with @, check that conn_id is not false:

change

```
 $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);
```

like that

```
if($this->conn_id){
    $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to initialize the connection if it is not available.
Change line #315:

```
if ($this->conn_id === FALSE)
{
    $this->initialize();
}
$str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too.
Wolfgang's solution works well for me.

And if you use codeIgniter, change database config 
`$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;` 
can also solve the problem.